# Can I use a cut-down Laravel for API development?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel for developing my API, but I was curious if there is a way to boost the performance even more by disable the things I don't need.

Like the CommandBus and the services which Laravel uses to render the views itself, because I'm only returning JSON and not using the features like CommandBus, view rendering etc.

Comment: Those services are generally only loaded if you use them.

Comment: +1 @ceejayoz if you want to be sure that nothing is loaded that you don't need simply remove the from the service provider list in app/config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, but the easiest thing to do to speed up your application would be to use route caching in Laravel 5.

Other than that, I guess general tips would be:

- Use nginx instead of Apache
- Use Myisam intead of innodb (if you're using MySQL and only doing reads)
- Read/write master slave configuration to do reads from the slave.

What response time are you getting and what is the response time that you would like?